# How can I render a empty grid view with Boolean table row in database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Morning everyone, I'm a newbie of c#.

The code below

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="insert_new_user" runat="server" OnClick="insert_new_user_Click" 
                CommandName="insertnewuser" Text="add new user" BorderColor="#000099">
</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Resign?" SortExpression="BS_DEPT">
    <ItemTemplate> 
         <asp:CheckBox ID="cb_isleave" runat="server"  Checked='<%# Eval("BS_LEAVE") %>'
                       Visible="True" Enabled="False" ForeColor="#ff0000" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:CheckBox ID="ed_cb_isleave" runat="server" Checked='<%#Eval("BS_LEAVE") %>' 
                       Visible="True" Enabled="true" ForeColor="#ff0000" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
         <asp:CheckBox ID="ft_cb_isleave" runat="server" Checked="false" 
                       Visible="True" Enabled="true" />
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

When the database is empty I use these code to render a empty footer row and header

```
protected void insert_new_user_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this._connectionString))
        {
            string fakequery_user = "SELECT TOP 1 [A].[BS_ID],[A].[BS_NAME_CHT],[BS_NAME_ENG] = ISNULL([A].[BS_NAME_ENG], '-'),[BS_LEAVE]=ISNULL([A].[BS_LEAVE],0),[B].[BS_NAME]" +
        "FROM[BS_USER][A] LEFT OUTER JOIN[BS_DEPT][B] ON[A].[BS_DEPT] = [B].[BS_ID]";
            SqlCommand fakequery = new SqlCommand(fakequery_user, conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(fakequery);
            SqlDataReader dr = fakequery.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                DataTable FinalUserData = this.Bulid_UserTB();
                conn.Close();
                conn.Open();
                da1.Fill(FinalUserData);
                DataSet datasetfinaluserdata = new DataSet();
                datasetfinaluserdata.Tables.Add(FinalUserData);
                conn.Close();
                da1.Dispose();

                USER_TABLE.DataSource = datasetfinaluserdata;
                USER_TABLE.DataBind();
                USER_TABLE.Rows[0].Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (USER_TABLE.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    renderEmptyGridView(USER_TABLE, "BS_ID, BS_NAME_CHT, BS_NAME_ENG, BS_NAME, BS_INSERTOR, BS_INSERT_TIME, BS_EDITOR, BS_EDIT_TIME, BS_LEAVE");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void renderEmptyGridView(GridView EmptyGridView, string FieldNames)
    {

        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
        char[] delimiterChars = { ',' };
        string[] colName = FieldNames.Split(delimiterChars);
        foreach (string myCol in colName)
        {
            DataColumn dColumn = new DataColumn(myCol.Trim());
            dTable.Columns.Add(dColumn);
        }
        DataRow dRow = dTable.NewRow();

        foreach (string myCol in colName)
        {
            dRow[myCol.Trim()] = DBNull.Value;
        }
        dTable.Rows.Add(dRow); 

        EmptyGridView.DataSourceID = null;
        EmptyGridView.DataSource = dTable;
        EmptyGridView.DataBind();
        EmptyGridView.Rows[0].Visible = false;
    }
```

> **but when I run the web, the error pop up said, "Specified cast is not valid."**

I think is it the `foreach()` is `string` but in the database the "`BS_LEAVE`" is a `Boolean`?

How can I solve it ? Thank You

Comment: Have you debugged your code?

Comment: Yes, I debugged